# как вывести данные из бд начиная с определенного id

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

```
$query = "SELECT id from products ORDER BY id LIMIT "
```

limit мне не подходит, мне нужно отсекать первые N строк и потом только выводить

Comment: *мне нужно отсекать первые N строк и потом только выводить* Если именно "первые N строк" - то как раз именно LIMIT и нужен. Вы посмотрите его описание в документации - в частности, прочитайте, что такое OFFSET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from products WHERE id >= определенный_id
```

Выводим записи, у которых `id` больше заданного